# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-aks

In Startup file, I am trying to inject the IHttpContextAccessor in constructor itself.

While running the API locally, IHttpContextAccessor is injected successfully in startup class. However when I am deploying the same to Azure kubernetes service, it fails and reported below exception. even pod state is crashloopbackoff.

Any suggestion how can I resolve this issue?

Here is the startup class.

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
        _logger.LogProcessStart();
    }
}
```

Here is the exception from pod logs.

```
    Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' whileattempting to activate 'API.Startup'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.LoadMethods(IServiceProvider hostingServiceProvider, Type startupType, String environmentName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContextcontext, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.EnsureStartup()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at API.Program.Main(String[] args) in /__w/1/s/src/API/Program.cs:line 18
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to [register IHttpContextAccessor service manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components).

**.net 6**

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

**.net 3.1,5**

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: thanks. this works. Along with this, I have retrieved service using getservice to access header data. var httpContextAccessor = sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

Comment: I was trying to use AddHttpContextAccessor() and it wouldn't compile. Finally, I found that the extension is in the nuget package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http". Took me too long to figure that out.

Comment: the nuget package "microsoft.aspnetcore.http" is deprecated as it is now included in the framework [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996557/microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-core-marked-as-deprecated-and-causing-publishing-errors]

Answer (score 1):

on ASP.NET 8 you can add on program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```